# IBM Dynamic Workload Console for Java352

Tags: workload-scheduler

Install IDWC for Java352, see pre-req of JazzSM and WAS. What components of JazzSM are required for IDWC? Not going to enable Tivoli Common Reporting. Is DB2 still required for JazzSM?

Answer (score 1):

The components of JazzSM required to install IDWC are "IBM Dashboard Application Services Hub" and "Jazz for Service Management extension for IBM WebSphere".

If you do NOT enable Tivoli Common Reporting then DB2 is not required to install the IDWC.